# How to close WebView or PDFView in Swift

Tags: swift, swift5

I've tried both of them to open PDF from a link but couldn't find a way to close or dismiss to return my original view. I've tried to create a button on top but didn't work. Is there any proper way to dismiss WebView or PDFView once they are opened?

Answer (score 0):

`UIWebView` and `PDFView` are both `UIView`'s. As such they cannot be "dismissed" like a `UIViewController`. Usually `UIView`'s are embedded in a `UIViewController`, so to hide your `PDFView`/`UIWebView` you would have to dismiss that parent controller.